# Rigify FK arm controls won't align to mesh

Tags: rigify

In the image you can see the rigify FK arm controls for two arms. On the left the two control circles are centered on the mesh, and on the right they're off center, leading to bad rotations. The obvious solution of pressing the "FK->IK" button doesn't work.
Does anyone know how to fix this, and what might be causing it?
Thanks.
[image]?

Comment: Obvious first question: Were the origins of both the mesh and armature centred on the X-axis before you parented the rig?